# Celery and Flask - Cannot mix new setting names with old setting names

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, celery

I have used [this tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/) to set up Celery on my Flask application but i keep getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 141, in data
    return self.callback()
celery.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:

Cannot mix new setting names with old setting names, please
rename the following settings to use the old format:

include                              -> CELERY_INCLUDE

Or change all of the settings to use the new format :)
```

What am i doing wrong? The code i used is basically the same of the tutorial:

****init**.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
app.config['TESTING'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery


app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379'
)
celery = make_celery(app)
```

Answer (score 3):

the code you are using used old variable names
change lines
`app.config.update(`
`CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379',`
`CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379'`
`)`
to
`app.config.update(`
`broker_url='redis://localhost:6379',`
`result_backend='redis://localhost:6379'`
`)`

Answer (score 0):

The similar Celery/Flask implementation was working fine on Ubuntu and Python 3.8, but giving errors as above on Windows 10 (Python 3.9.0 and Celery 4.4.6 (cliffs)).

It finally worked for me by adding -P solo to the celery worker command (ref - https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3759)

$ celery worker -A proj -Q yourqueuename -P solo --loglevel=INFO